# DataViewWebPart - Can We access the property bag value from the XSLT of DVWP

Tags: data-view-web-part, xslt

DataViewWebPart - Can We access the property bag value from the XSLT of DVWP?

Answer (score 2):

You can if you use the Lists Web Service as your DataSource.

Comment: How would you go about setting that up, out of curiosity? This area's a bit fuzzy for me, so DVWPs and web services don't seem to be quite related.

Comment: The original question was pretty vague, but I just learned this trick recently: http://sympmarc.com/2011/06/30/getting-ows_metainfo-nicely-with-spservices/. I suppose it depends on which property bag asknithin wants to access. You can use a Web Service as your DataSource in a DVWP, like lists and libraries, database connections, XML files, and server side scripts.

Comment: I've just starting reading up on this subject (very interesting). The following may be useful for other beginners in this area: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/data-view-web-part-the-basics-insert-a-dvwp-on-your-page.aspx